# Duplicate characters in a string

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I a beginner in python. I am building a small program that can find any duplicate characters in a string. However there's something i don't understand.

Code:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    dict = {}
    for letter in string:
        dict[letter] = 1
    if letter in dict:
        dict[letter] += 1
    return dict


print(is_isogram("Dermatoglyphics"))
```

OUTPUT
{'D': 1, 'e': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 1, 'a': 1, 't': 1, 'o': 1, 'g': 1, 'l': 1, 'y': 1, 'p': 1, 'h': 1, 'i': 1, 'c': 1, **'s': 2**}

I set an empty dictionary.
I then used a for loop to iterate over the string, and then in each iteration it should assign 1 to a dictionary key, "letter"

Then used "if...in" to check if letter has already appeared, and if it has then the the "letter" key should be incremented by 1.

I tried it on a word, Dermatoglyphics, but each time the last key value pair is always 2, even though this word only contains 1 of each letter. Does anyone know why?

Comment: The `if` statement applies to the last occurrence only, as an after thought at the end of the loop

Comment: The if-part should be in the for-loop, not after (and some adjustments are needed). Don't use builtin names like "dict" as variables.

Comment: Thank you all so much, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting 1 for each, and then you increment the last letter. I think you meant to put `if` inside `for` block.

Here is a working version:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    dct = {}
    for letter in string:
        if letter in dct:
            dct[letter] += 1
        else:
            dct[letter] = 1
    return dct


print(is_isogram("Dermatoglyphics"))
```

The logic behind: If the letter already exists, increment counter. Otherwise initialize it with counter=1.

Edit: Changed `dict` to `dct` as `dict` is a python built-in name as @Michael suggested.

Comment: Yeah you are right adding two loops does add up time. Deleted my answer and upvoted yours.

Comment: hey Please look into this.
Your implementation: https://onlinegdb.com/eeV0IFN5J
The program I posted: https://onlinegdb.com/lMC-Qn76D
They are both timed.

Comment: @ZohaibHamdule You need a really really long string as input for time complexity comparisons. The time can differ in short strings.

Answer (score 2):

`if` statement applies after finishing `for` loop, so that it adds 1 only in last character. Its a problem of indentation. Even if you write if condition inside loop, it won't be right because of your logic. You assign `dict[letter] = 1` for every letter. Then check `if letter in dict`, so that it will add 1 two times. Use else condition instead.

```
def is_isogram(string):
    dict = {}
    for letter in string:
        if letter in dict:
            dict[letter] += 1
        else:
            dict[letter] = 1
    return dict

print(is_isogram("Dermatoglyphics"))
```

Or you can use `count` function like this

```
def is_isogram(string):
    dict = {}
    for letter in string:
        dict[letter] = string.count(letter)
    return dict

print(is_isogram("Dermatoglyphics"))
```

Comment: The second option is O(n^2). For anything real, just use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Which one would be faster in the long run, count or an if? I think count uses C implementation which might be fast, but I am not sure how to compare with if comparison.

Answer (score 1):

As your function is named `is_isogram()` it should return a boolean.
Either the string is an isogram either it isn't.
A big benefit is that you stop iterating as soon as you find a duplicate.

You don't need to use a `dict`.
It's not a bad idea but to detect an isogram you don't have the need to count occurrences of each letter.
You just have to test the membership.
A `set` is better suited. Like a dict but without the values.

```py
def is_isogram(word: str) -> bool:
    used_letters = set()
    for letter in word:
        if letter in used_letters:
            return False
        else:
            used_letters.add(letter)
    return True

is_isogram("Dermatoglyphics")  # True
is_isogram("DDermatoglyphics")  # False
```

Comment: thanks, and I agree that I don't need a dictionary. But I still don't get it, what is the if statement used for? How exactly is it used to check that a letter is not repeated In the iteration?

Answer (score 0):

""""This code will create two lists one with duplicates & another with #non duplicates in word or string"""

```
    y = []
    z = []
    def dupinword(dupword):
         for i in dupword:
             x = dupword.count(i)
             if x>1:
                y.append(i)
                print(y)
                print(len(y))
             else:
                z.append(i)
                print(z)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code works exactly as it is expected it assigns 1 to every letter then since your if condition is out of the loop, it increments the last character (letter) by one.

I made some changes to your code.

```
def is_isogram(string):
    dict = {}
    for letter in string:
        dict[letter] = 0
    for letter in string:
        dict[letter] += 1
    return dict


print(is_isogram("telegram"))
```

What I have done is that first it adds all the letters to the dictionary then uses another scan to count each letter.

This function has a complexity of O(n) which is faster than other answers I think

Here is a timed execution of both
This answer: https://onlinegdb.com/lMC-Qn76D
Other answers: https://onlinegdb.com/eeV0IFN5J

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You do not need to loop the same dictionary twice. It is unnecessary calculation. See other answers.

Comment: @Minot It makes the function faster. Since if there is a single loop we will increase the number of comparisons. The outer scan of the string will have complexity of O(n) and the inner condition which checks if the letter already exists will have a complexity of O(n) resulting in overall complexity of O(n^2).

Comment: Plain comparisons does not increase the time complexity.

Comment: @Minot to check if a letter exist in a list, we need to compare it against every element in that list. That is not a plain comparison. Using the statement "if letter in used_letter" will have a complexity of O(n)